# Input CSV, picking a specfic column and outputing it as a txt file

Tags: r

I'm looking to do the following in R.

Read in a CSV.
Keep a specific column and remove, or freeze the remainder.
Export it to a .txt file

This is what I have thus far

```
bankData = read.csv("bank-full.csv", header = FALSE)

newBankData <- bankData[1]

write.csv(newBankData, file = "newBankData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Using this merges all data into one column,

Any advice?

EDIT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLcqq.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "merges all data into one column"? You didn't post any example of your data and it's impossible to guess

Comment: Part of the reason this question is confusing is that you appear to say that you want to pull out one column and write it to a file. Your code appears to do that, and then you say it doesn't work because it pulls out just one column. Huh?

Comment: I have added an image of what happens in my post. Basically all columns and data, is all mergered into just one column. IE everything ends up in column A.

Comment: Perhaps your file is not actually comma delimited? Have you opened it and actually looked at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image posted seems to indicate the data is delimited by semicolon, not comma.

try again with sep = ";".

```
bankData = read.csv("bank-full.csv", header = FALSE, sep=";")

newBankData <- bankData[1]

write.csv(newBankData, file = "newBankData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you

Comment: How would I take a random sample of data - iv used head(newBankData, 1000), but no joy. Also how would I delete a value that has a certain paratmeter